# creating many lists from list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have created a list of lists through list comprehension and would like to unravel
this list of lists into many lists through iteration (with the variable name of each list iterating aswell), is that possible?
as to what exactly i mean by that i want:

```
listoflists = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5,6,7],["a","b"]]
```

with the output being:

```
list1=[1,2,3]
list2=[2,3,4]
list3=[3,4,5,6,7]
list4=["a","b"]
```

so i not only get the unraveled lists but also the names of each list iterating with range(len(listoflists)).

For clarification as to why i need this, for my project i want to write a csv file with each column containing one of those lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider forming a dictionary, where your separate lists are captured in the key-value pairs:

```
>>> manylists = {f'list{i}': j for i, j in enumerate(listoflists, 1)}
>>> manylists
{'list1': [1, 2, 3], 'list2': [2, 3, 4],
 'list3': [3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 'list4': ['a', 'b']}
```

This roughly mimics the "dynamic variable creation" that you are trying to do, but instead of all of those lists floating around in your local namespace, they are all wrapped up in one neat data structure (a dictionary), called `manylists`.

You can also use simply `dict(enumerate(listoflists, 1))`, where the resulting keys will be ints starting at 1 and ascending from there.

Comment: ok i was allready wondering if a dictionary would be the way to go, will i be able to access each dictionary element (name and list) and write it out in a csv file?

Comment: Yes, but in that case, why not simply iterate through the list itself?  Do you have a specific reason for accessing "list1", "list2" as those names explicitly?

Comment: Gotta run but overall, consider just working with each list element directly rather than creating an intermediate data structure if that's not really required.  (For example, see the `open('myfile.csv', 'w').writelines(...)`

Comment: well to put it roughly, i have many lists with measured values of sensors. For some of those sensor types i have many sensors (meaning they measure the same thing), so for those i created the list of lists(coming from how the data i got was structured), but in the end i want to write them out in a column each.

Comment: for more clarification, since there are many sensors (for temperatur for example 20+) an iteration is needed.

Answer (score -2):

You can iterate in your list of list with a simple for

```
for list in listoflists:
```

And then print it in the format you want.